# Resetting kernel hyperparameter values in GPflow

Tags: python, machine-learning, gaussian, gpflow

My use case is this: I have a function that takes in a kernel of the user's choice then I will iterate through every date in the dataset and use a Gaussian Process Regression to estimate the model using the specified kernel. However, since I'm pointing to the kernel object, I need to reset it to the default values before I run the next iteration.

```
import gpflow

class WrapperClass(object):
    def __init__(self, kernel):
        super().__init__()
        self.kernel = kernel

    def fit(self, X, y):
        m = gpflow.models.GPR(X, y, self.kernel) # I need to reset the kernel here

# some code later
def some_function(Xs, ys, ts, f):
    for t in ts:
        X = Xs.loc[t]    # pandas dataframe
        y = ys.loc[t]    # pandas
        f.fit(X, y)

k1 = gpflow.kernels.RBF(1)
k2 = gpflow.kernels.White(0.1)
k = k1 + k2
f = WrapperClass(k)
sume_function(Xs, ys, ts, f)
```

I've found the method read_trainables() on the kernel so one strategy is to save the settings the user has provided, but there doesn't seem to be any way to set them?

```
In [7]: k1.read_trainables()
Out[7]: {'Sum/rbf/lengthscales': array(1.), 'Sum/rbf/variance': array(1.)}
```

Cheers,
Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the parameters of Parameterized objects (models, kernels, likelihoods etc) using assign(): `k1.assign(k1.read_trainables())` (or some other dict of path-value pairs). You might as well create a new kernel object, though!

Note that each time you create new parameterized objects - this applies both to kernels and models, as in your fit() method - you add operations to the tensorflow graph, which can slow down graph computation significantly if it grows a lot. You probably want to look into manually handling tf.Graph() and tf.Session() to keep them distinct for each model. (See the notebooks on [session handling](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/understanding/tf_graphs_and_sessions.ipynb) and further [tips and tricks](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/GPflow/GPflow/blob/develop/doc/source/notebooks/tips_and_tricks.ipynb) in the new GPflow documentation.)

Comment: Thanks, I've started using a neural network rather than GP for my use case, but thanks for your reply.

Comment: @swmfg would you mind accepting this answer, then? ta:)